# Largest/smallest (NOT min/max) of a list of integers (negatives included)

Tags: python, integer

(I couldn't find any min/max examples using negative integers.)

I am trying to write a simple program that will find the "largest" and "smallest" of 3 user-defined integers. This would be too easy if I am just intended to find the minimum and maximum.

I think I am being asked to write a program that finds the min/max of absolute values of these numbers and then remembers what number generated the biggest/smallest, even if it was negative.
This sounds slightly complicated though and this is an introductory course. Can someone tell me what the simplest solution to this problem is?

Currently my program only finds min/max:

```
print("This program will find the \"biggest\" \n"
      "and \"smallest\" of three integers. \n"
      "Please enter Num1: ")
while True:
  try:
     nNum1 = int(input())
  except ValueError:
     print("Please enter an integer. \n")
     continue
  else:
     print("You have entered " + str(nNum1) + ". \n")
     break
print("Please enter Num2: ")
while True:
  try:
     nNum2 = int(input())
  except ValueError:
     print("Please enter an integer. \n")
     continue
  else:
     print("You have entered " + str(nNum2) + ". \n")
     break
print("Please enter Num3: ")
while True:
  try:
     nNum3 = int(input())
  except ValueError:
     print("Please enter an integer. \n")
     continue
  else:
     print("You have entered " + str(nNum3) + ". \n")
     break

nMin = min(abs(nNum1), abs(nNum2), abs(nNum3))
print("The *smallest* of these three numbers is " + str(nMin) + ". \n")
nMax = max(abs(nNum1), abs(nNum2), abs(nNum3))
print("The *largest* of these three numbers is " + str(nMax) + ". \n")
```

Comment: without `abs` this works fine. why do you need `abs`

Comment: Yes, @L_Church is write, maybe there is misunderstanding here, could you please write out an example ?

Comment: not looking for min/max, looking for "largest" number and "smallest" number. Min/Max is basically looking for what is furthest at either end of the number line. I want closest to/furthest from zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) with `abs` as the key function, and the smallest number will be the first item of the resulting list, while the largest number will be the last item.

```
>>> a = [-5, -8, 2]
>>> sorted(a, key=abs)[0]
2
>>> sorted(a, key=abs)[-1]
-8
>>>
```

Comment: does using -1 as the index as you have return the last value in the sorted list?

Comment: @user391838 Yes in Python negative index means counting backwards from the end of the list.